# How to resize multiple icons (centered in multiple artboards) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, transform

I have multiple versions of a logo (different colours, keylines etc) laid out in a file on multiple artboards. This so I can save off in batches multiple .PNGs from the one file.

My problem is I now need to decrease the size of the artwork (by 75%) **but can't seem to keep artwork centered on artboards?**

Answer (score 3):

Select all of your logo versions and then go to `Object > Transform > Transform Each...`

Select 75% for both scale factors like this:

[image]

Hit OK and you're done.

Comment: Important to this answer is the fact that the little constraint box is set to "center" in both dimensions. If that's set to the upper-left corner (which, I think is the default?) then the artwork will shrink toward the upper-left. Also important: artworks need to be grouped or otherwise made into a single selectable entity...if the logos are still in pieces, then the pieces will shrink in place.

Comment: Both good points. I think that scale from centre (as shown in the screenshot) is the default, but still worth noting.